# How to make an item only break certain blocks after applying the enchantment and unbreakable parts of the command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My command is

```
give @p stone_pickaxe 1 0 {
    display:{
        Name:"Level 1 Pickaxe",
        Lore:["A basic pickaxe."]
    },
    ench:[{
        id:32,lvl:1
    }],
    Unbreakable:1
} {
    CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]
}
```

How would i add the next part? (only allowed to break stone blocks)

Comment: You're going to have to add some more information. What is "The next part"? I'm assuming the `CanDestroy` command? If so, part of the problem is that it does not belong to the same command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 1):

In Adventure Mode you can only break blocks featured in the CanDestroy tag of the held item. Otherwise the character won't even try to break the block. So just set the player to Adventure Mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but I noticed that your command has some errors. Here's the revised command:
`give @p stone_pickaxe 1 0 {display:{Name:"Level 1 Pickaxe",Lore:["A basic pickaxe."]},ench:[{id:32,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1,CanDestroy["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
/give @p stone_pickaxe 1 0 {display:{Name:"Level 1 Pickaxe",Lore:["A basic pickaxe."]},ench:[{id:32,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1,CanDestroy["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]}
```