# How to get a tool that can only break specific blocks and has a name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, right now I'm using this:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {CanDestroy:[minecraft:stone]}
```

But I need one that also has the `Name` value. Anyone know this one?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275562/how-to-make-an-item-only-break-certain-blocks-after-applying-the-enchantment-and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size (tested with latest minecraft version):

```
give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 
{
    CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"],
    display:
    {
        Name:"Veritus' Pickaxe",
        Lore:["It breaks stone and stone bricks."]
    }
}
```